# Work on vector field $= 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

I am doing the problem

Calculate the work done in a moving particle along the given path

$F=<yze^x+xyze^x,xze^x,xye^x>$ along $C: r(t)= <2\cos t,3\sin t,0>$

$1≤t≤2$

I found that this field was conservative, so I was able to set up a potential function

$f=xyze^x+C$

From there to calculate work I did

$f_{end}-f_{start} $

This gives me zero though because of the z component. Is this correct or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Showing requested work

$r(t)= <2\cos t,3\sin t,0>$
$1≤t≤2$

$r(1)= <2\cos(1),3\sin (1),0>$

$r(2)= <2\cos (2),3\sin (2),0>$

$f_{end}-f_{start} $

$ 0 - 0 = 0 $

Comment: There is no way to know unless you show the work you used to get your results.

Comment: That is correct. The potential function is $xyze^x$. The work done is zero as $z = 0$ at both start and end points.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.